# localStorage no está definido en un Guard de Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

Tengo una aplicación en angular y quiero validar el acceso a rutas con un Guard, la idea es recuperar un objeto del sessionStorage para validarlo, sin embargo cuando entro a la ruta protegida el navegador me muestra este error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

no sé por qué me marca ese error, en un componente agrego el objeto al localstorage y lo puedo ver desde el navegador, pero cuando entra al guard me sale ese error

este es mi guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class ProtectGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        console.warn("validando");
        if (localStorage.getItem('ex-token'))
            return true;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tuve este problema con un proyecto en angular legacy, lo termine solucionando al implementar angular2-cool-storage.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cool-storage

El uso es simple

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CoolLocalStorage } from 'angular2-cool-storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
    localStorage: CoolLocalStorage;

    constructor(localStorage: CoolLocalStorage) {
        this.localStorage = localStorage;   
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.localStorage.setItem('itemKey', 'itemValue');

        console.log(this.localStorage.getItem('itemKey'));

        this.localStorage.setObject('itemKey', {
            someObject: 3
        });

        console.log(this.localStorage.getObject('itemKey'));
    }
}
```

Dentro de las pruebas anteriores al uso de cool-storage

habíamos visto que el problema se generaba porque se hacia uso de local storage en partes del codigo que correspondían al servidor.
En un principio lo solucionamos consultándolo en `isPlatformBrowser` https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser en caso de ser true haciamos uso de localstorage, pero por alguna razon no siempre funcionaba. Por esto terminamos volcandonos en cool-storage.

Comment: Me ha funcionado muchas gracias, pero me queda la duda... cuando mencionas "se hacia uso de local storage en partes del codigo que correspondían al servidor" a que te refieres y como puedo identificar que parte corresponde al servidor?

Comment: Con la Api Common la fc isPlatformBrowser() lo identificas

Comment: Como mencionó en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

eso pasa por un problema de conversion, se soluciona simple si lo pasas a boleano directamente de la siguiente forma

```
if(!!localStorage.getItem('ex-token'))
```

con esa linea se deberia solucionar y obtener el item